# Max source dates from all joined tables during data warehouse incremental build

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, max, data-warehouse

I have a data warehouse query that builds a fact table by joining 14 source tables. Each source table has a source_timestamp field to indicate the time the record was inserted or updated.  I need to pull the max source_timestamp for each row of the query result from each of the 14 source tables.  This will allow me to know the max update date for each row of the fact table.

I wanted to do something like this for the last field in the query...

```
(
    SELECT MAX(Source_Timestamp)
    FROM (
        VALUES a.source_timestamp, b.source_timestamp, c.source_timestamp, ...
    ) AS UpdateDate(Source_Timestamp)
) AS LastUpdateDate
```

However, I get an incorrect syntax error because the subquery doesn't know a., b., or c. in the query context.  I was hoping the VALUES clause would help me out but apparently not.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault for not being more careful with the coding.  I should've guessed from the fact that it was a syntax error.  I needed to enclose each of the items in the `VALUES` clause in () like:

```
(
    SELECT MAX(Source_Timestamp)
    FROM (
        VALUES (a.source_timestamp), (b.source_timestamp), (c.source_timestamp),(...)
    ) AS UpdateDate(Source_Timestamp)
) AS LastUpdateDate
```

Comment: Note that this gives you them in separate rows, if that is what you wanted. If you want separate columns and a single row, put them all in one big `()` and give each a column alias `AS UpdateDate(col1, col2, col3....)`

Comment: Thanks.  Yes this is what I need.  I want to know the latest date any of the component source tables are updated so that when I build the fact table I can see the latest date that any data on that row was changed.  This will allow me to do incremental updates to the data warehouse.